# AWS credentials during Docker build process

Tags: docker, dockerfile, aws-cli

As part of the process to build my docker container I need to pull some files from an s3 bucket but I keep getting `fatal error: Unable to locate credentials` even though for now I am setting the credentials as `ENV` vars (though would like to know of a better way to do this)

So when building the container I run

```
docker build -t my-container --build-arg AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="region" --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY="key" --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="key" . --squash
```

And in my Dockerfile I have

```
ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY

ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

RUN /bin/bash -l -c "aws s3 cp s3://path/to/folder/ /my/folder --recursive"
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this (I know there is an option to add a config file but that just seems an unnecessary extra step as I should be able to read from ENV).

Comment: In addition to environment variable name mentioned in an answer below, you also don't need `ENV` here as you seem to be only needing it in build step. `ARG` will be enough in this case and variable will not persist in the image.

Comment: Thanks for the info :-)

Comment: Just passing in my assumed role creds as args worked for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name of the environment variable is `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` vs `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`

You can review the full list from [amazon doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html)

> The following variables are supported by the AWS CLI
>
> `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` – AWS access key.
>
> `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` – AWS secret key. Access and secret key
>   variables override credentials stored in credential and config files.
>
> `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` – session token. A session token is only required if
>   you are using temporary security credentials.
>
> `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` – AWS region. This variable overrides the default
>   region of the in-use profile, if set.
>
> `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` – name of the CLI profile to use. This can be the
>   name of a profile stored in a credential or config file, or default to
>   use the default profile.
>
> `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` – path to a CLI config file.