# Build ASP.NET Core 2.2 Docker Image with AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, amazon-systems-manager

**Setup**

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Professional 2017
- Docker CE v 2.0.0.3
- ASP.NET Core 2.2
- PowerShell v6.1.0

I'm using the AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store to hold an encrypted connection string for my ASP.NET app.

I found [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-dotnet-extensions-configuration) extension to configure the Parameter Store within my app as follows:

**Program.cs**

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddSystemsManager(configureSource =>
            {
                var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT").ToLower();
                configureSource.Path = $"/my-app-name/{env}";

                configureSource.Optional = false;
            });
        });
```

This all works fine when I build, run or test the app in Visual Studio because I have an `appsettings.json` file that configures the aws profile for the .NET SDK

```json
"AWS": {
    "Profile": "default",
    "Region": "eu-west-1"
}
```

However, I now want to build the image locally.  I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233113/aws-credentials-during-docker-build-process) StackOverflow post which describes passing the AWS credentials as arguments to the `docker build` command

My `Dockerfile` looks like this (I've removed the runtime stage for brevity):

```bash
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2.100-sdk AS build
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config
RUN dotnet build MyApp.sln --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM build as unittest
WORKDIR /src/tests/MyApp.UnitTests
RUN dotnet test

FROM build as integrationtest
WORKDIR /src/tests/MyApp.IntegrationTests
RUN dotnet test
```

When I run my build command:

```powershell
docker build -t my-org/my-app:1.0.0-integrationtest `
    --build-arg AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="eu-west-1" `
    --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="my-access-key" `
    --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="my-secret-key" `
    --target integrationtest .
```

**The Problem**

My integration tests fail because my app can't connect to the AWS Parameter Store

FYI - I have added the connection string as an environment variable in my Dockerfile and everything works successfully (so I know the previous statement is true)

So the question is: *How can I pass AWS credentials to my .net core app when it is building locally inside a docker container?*

If it helps, here is the error from PowerShell:

```
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Connection refused) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: APITestsFixture`1 fixture)
---- System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Connection refused
-------- System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Connection refused
---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: APITestsFixture`1 fixture
Stack Trace:

----- Inner Stack Trace #1 (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException) -----
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task`1 getTask)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass1_1`1.<<RunSync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.ExclusiveSynchronizationContext.BeginMessageLoop() in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\_mobile\AsyncHelpers.cs:line 142
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task) in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\_mobile\AsyncHelpers.cs:line 87
   at Amazon.Util.AWSSDKUtils.DownloadStringContent(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout, IWebProxy proxy) in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\AWSSDKUtils.cs:line 1008
   at Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.GetItems(String relativeOrAbsolutePath, Int32 tries, Boolean slurp) in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\_bcl+netstandard\EC2InstanceMetadata.cs:line 513
   at Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.get_IAMSecurityCredentials() in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\_bcl+netstandard\EC2InstanceMetadata.cs:line 311
   at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials() in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\_bcl+netstandard\DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.cs:line 142
   at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentials() in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\_bcl+netstandard\DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.cs:line 88
   at Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentialsAsync() in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\_bcl+netstandard\DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.cs:line 106
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:line 90
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext) in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line 137
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager.Internal.SystemsManagerProcessor.GetParametersByPathAsync()
   at Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager.Internal.SystemsManagerProcessor.GetDataAsync()
   at Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager.SystemsManagerConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync(Boolean reload)
   at Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager.SystemsManagerConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer..ctor(IWebHostBuilder builder, IFeatureCollection featureCollection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateServer(IWebHostBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient(WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions options)
   at MyApp.IntegrationTests.TestsFixture`1..ctor() in /src/tests/MyApp.IntegrationTests/TestsFixture.cs:line 20
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
----- Inner Stack Trace #2 (Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException) -----
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional ENV lines after your ARGS to your docker file

```
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
```